# Python - How to change the name of a section use configparser?

Tags: python, string, ini, configparser

Here is my ini file

```
[456789a]
IP=192.168.1.73
AGENTID=1
NEEDSYNCDEFBAK=-1
GROUP=5
[123456]
IP=192.168.1.73
AGENTID=2
NEEDSYNCDEFBAK=-1
GROUP=2
```

So..Can I just use configparser to change the name of a section(like..456789a)?

if can't, here is another solution.

1. read ini file
2. find "[456789a]"
3. replace "[4567891]" to "[name]"
4. use configparser reread this ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a simple search and replace, like in the alternative you have provided, might be risky. It might change some occurrence of that string that you might not want changed.

To guarantee a safe replace, it is better to use the power of `ConfigParser` itself. We will use `ConfigParser` to implement something similar to your alternative. Here is a pseudo-code/algorithm with some methods you can use to achieve this (customized to your question):

1) Read the *ini* file using something like:

```
_config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
with open(your_config_file) as config_file:
    _config.readfp(config_file)
```

2) Get all the options as *(name, value)* pairs for the section you want to rename:

```
my_section_to_rename = "456789a"
my_section_items = _config.items(section_to_rename)
```

3) Add a section with the new name you want to give, as a new section:

```
my_section_new_name = "newSectionName"
_config.add_section(my_section_new_name)
```

4) Add all the options from the previous section items to this new one:

```
for option,value in my_section_items:
    _config.set(my_section_new_name, option, value)
```

5) Remove the old section from the `ConfigParser` object:

```
_config.remove_section(my_section_to_rename)
```

6) Now write this to the *ini* file to finish up the process.

```
with open(your_config_file) as config_file:
    _config.write(your_config_file)
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) on all these methods and classes regarding `ConfigParser`.

Hope that was useful.